# Where are scientific references for the claims made in "Thinking Fast and Slow"

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, decision-making

I am currently reading fast and slow and the author mentions the results of **a lot** of studies. However, these are not directly cited, although some can possibly be googled with the information given.

I was wondering if there exists a version with all the references **or** an academic book which provides similar information and references. I don't have much knowledge on the subject, so I do not know the technical terms for some of the phenomena explained in the book, and thus I do not know how to look for the papers pertaining them. (A suggestion of how familiarize myself with such terms is also welcome).

Comment: Good question. I've had a book called Judgement and decision making which discusses a lot of tversky and kahneman's studies, but also others. I am unable to find the reference to it, however. I'll post it as soon as I find it!

Comment: Does the version of the book you have lack the citations? My copy has notes for each chapter and most of the notes contain direct references to the literature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the book I used to study decision making. It's called Judgement and Decision Making and is written by Daniel and David Hardman. It is a perfect introductory book on the topic with references to pretty recent literature. It covers much of Tversky and Kahneman's work (the latter being the author of Thinking Fast and Slow), but also refer to literature of many other good research. I think this book may be the best scientific approximation of Thinking Fast and Slow.

[Hardman, D. K. & Hardman, D., (2009). Judgment and decision making: Psychological perspectives (Vol. 11). John Wiley & Sons.](https://books.google.nl/books?hl=nl&lr=&id=MhwKMSpf818C&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Judgment%20and%20Decision%20Making:%20Psychological%20Perspectives&ots=2YpXhfOI2Y&sig=oAcpMr9NPn4ZY8ErDpoRTqGPN-U#v=onepage&q=Judgment%20and%20Decision%20Making%3A%20Psychological%20Perspectives&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the result of the work of Kahnemman and Tversky leaded is the Prospect Theory ([Kahneman, D., & Tversky, A. (1979). Prospect theory: An analysis of decision under risk. Econometrica: Journal of the econometric society, 263-291.](https://scholar.google.se/scholar?hl=en&q=prospect%20theory&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=&oq=prospe)). The main components of that theory are include in that book ("Think fast and Slow"). So, I believe that that paper you can provide you with more reference on the work of these two authors.

Comment: If you elaborate just a bit more on this answer on why this one particular paper is relevant as opposed to a full book, this could constitute an answer. Furthermore, full APA references are preferred (e.g., check Robin's answer); these can easily be found on Google Scholar.